# Trigger is not working in MySQL when record is updated using Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to update a record in a table (say the Employee table) using an android app, where all business logic is written in PHP.

The table has a simple trigger on it, which executes when any kind of update operation is done on the Employee table (say the trigger will log the previous/old values of the record to a table named emp_log).

So, the issue starts from here onwards. I fetch the data into an android app,  I make some changes and revert/save it within the app. When I check the Employee table, I can see the updated record, but the trigger on this table does not make changes to the logging table(emp_log).

But when I update any record through the MySQL editor on my PHP server, the trigger works perfectly. i.e. Consider I update the salary for an employee with `ID=1` using the default editor of PHP MySQL (This time I'm not updating records using the android app), I then record the updated result in the `Employee` table and the trigger successfully logs data to logging table(emp_log).

This is the SQL I use for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_emp_trg AFTER UPDATE ON employee FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO emp_log VALUES (old.empid, old.name, old.sal);
```

In-short, the trigger does not work when I update any record using the android app, while the trigger works perfect when the backend is used for updating.